# Reset TextField value using Combine and Swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I try to reset a `TextField` value when a certain condition is met `(.count == 4)`, but it does not work, what am I missing?

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var code = ""
    private var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable?
    init() {
        anyCancellable = $code.sink { (newVal) in
            if newVal.count == 4 {
                self.code = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("My code", text: $viewModel.code)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` seems to fix this issue, however, I am not entirly sure why it is needed.

On a side note, make sure you capture [weak self] in a sink block to avoid memory leaks:

```
anyCancellable = $code
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main) // <--
            .sink { [weak self] newVal in
                if newVal.count == 4 {
                    self?.code = ""
            }
```

Comment: It's needed because `code` have to be changed on the main thread in order to have an UI effect

Comment: @SorinLica,  this is an unnecessary overkill to observe the value changes through `@Published` in order to reset it. It's supported out-the-box in the language with `didSet`

Comment: I agree with @SorinLica in this matter. I think their answer is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where you don't need any Combine. Just use the normal `didSet` to observe changes to the property:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var code = "" {
        didSet {
            if code.count == 4 {
                self.code = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```